# The "NegativeNumbers" parameter is missing a value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS that has two datasets. One dataset `NegativeNumbers` returns one column with 0 or more values that are used in the main dataset.

The problem comes when `@NegativeNumbers` has no value to be passed I get the error:

> The NegativeNumbers parameter is missing a value.

The NegativeNumbers query will not always return a value (this is correct), so I need the main dataset to execute correctly still when there is no value. I thought checking "Allow empty values" would take care of that, but no.

The parameter `@NegativeNumbers` is hidden, so it won't take a null value, even though I have it checked to allow empty values and multiple values. The default value is set to the `NegativeNumbers` dataset values. Hidden ones don't like available values.

Here is the basic code for NegativeNumbers dataset:

```
select colName
where  colName < 0 -- returns all values less than 0 as values
                   -- for parameter "NegativeNumbers"
```

Here is the basic code for the main dataset:

```
select bunchOfColumns
from   mytable
where  aColumnName in (@NegativeNumbers)
       -- this returns only the values where the column value is a match for one
       -- of the values returned by the @NegativeNumbers dataset
```

The actual query is much more complicated than this and includes a union all statement, but this illustrates what I am trying to do. If the first query does not return any values, then the second gives me the error. Why would it not just substitute "`in ('')`" for the value of the `@NegativeNumbers` if the dataset is empty and the "allow empty value" is checked?

I have scoured Google. No luck. I have played with the different parameter options. No luck. I have rebuilt the report. And nothing. I always get this error, but I don't know how to fix it.

*beating my head on my desk, questioning the meaning of my coding existence.
*sigh

This is some advanced SSRS stuff and I am not the best at explaining so if there are any questions that would help clarify what I am trying to do, ask away.

Comment: "The parameter -@NegativeNumbers - is hidden, so it won't take a null value" - that doesn't sound right to me. Making a parameter hidden does not prevent it accepting a NULL value, which is what will be returned if your dataset returns no results.

Comment: Can you try updating your available values dataset query to something like `SELECT CAST(Nr AS VARCHAR(20)) FROM NumTable WHERE Nr < 0 UNION ALL SELECT ''`?

Comment: @Nathan Sorry, I can't have null with a multi value, which I need in case I get more than 1 result that is negative.

Comment: I have a union all as my main dataset. My db table looks like this:

Comment: I have a union all as my main dataset. My db table (for this example) has 3 rows and each look like this: row1) 123456, 01, -5.50 row 2) 123456, 01, 5.50, row 3) 987654, 01, 4.35. The first two numbers make up a key and if that key has rows with negative numbers, I grab them and if it does not have negative numbers, then I grab all the positives. The trouble comes when I have no negative numbers to return. Ssrs then spazzes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did a workaround to where my NegativeNumbers will always return a dataset.

```
    if exists (select query)
    then select query
    else '2'         
     //my key will never equal 2 so the main dataset will 
    //always return the results from  only the positives
```

Yay for easy workarounds!